# How to remove sublists whose difference of two elements is either 1 or 11?

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

I want to create a list of 3-element subsets of $\{1,2,\cdots,12\}$ where no two elements in each subset can have difference of 1 or 11. I am trying to solve the following:

> Find the number of all possible triangles that can be created by choosing 3 points of a 12-sided polygon, but no sides of the triangles are also the sides of the polygon.

The following attempt fails because it returns just a list of all subsets without restriction.

```
Select[Subsets[Range[12], {3}]
 , (Abs[#[[1]] - #[[2]]] != 1 || Abs[#[[1]] - #[[2]]] != 11) &&
   (Abs[#[[1]] - #[[3]]] != 1 || Abs[#[[1]] - #[[3]]] != 11) &&
   (Abs[#[[3]] - #[[2]]] != 1 || Abs[#[[3]] - #[[2]]] != 11) &]
```

## Edit

I just got the solution as follows, but can it be simplified?

```
Select[Subsets[Range[12], {3}]
  , ! MemberQ[{1, 11}, Abs[#[[1]] - #[[2]]]] &&
    ! MemberQ[{1, 11}, Abs[#[[1]] - #[[3]]]] &&
    ! MemberQ[{1, 11}, Abs[#[[3]] - #[[2]]]] &] // Length
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
test[sublist_] := ContainsNone[Abs[Subtract @@@ Subsets[sublist,{2}]], {1,11}]

Select[Subsets[Range[12], {3}], test]
```

For your problem in the comments, the number of triangles in a regular polygon which do not share any sides with that polygon is $n (n - 4) (n - 5)/6$ provided $n\ge6$. It would be much more efficient to use this result directly than to list them and count them.

Comment: If you want an anonymous function in select this is `Select[Subsets[Range[12], {3}], ContainsNone[Abs[Subtract @@@ Subsets[#, {2}]], {1, 11}] &]`

Comment: Thank you. A nice idea! I am waiting for a couple of hours to accept.

Answer (score 3):

You may use [`SubsetCount`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SubsetCount.html). This is an experimental function in version 12.1.1 so behaviour may change.

```
Select[
  SubsetCount[#, {j_, k_} /; Or @@ Thread[j - k == {1, 11}]] == 0 &
  ]@Subsets[Range[12], {3}]
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much! A  nice info.

Answer (score 2):

This should be quite a bit faster than your original solution:

```
Select[Subsets[Range[12], {3}], ! MemberQ[Abs[ListCorrelate[{-1, 1}, #, 1]], 1 | 11] &]
```

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Not an answer,only a review.

the question is equivalence to
$$1\leq a < b <c \leq 12,b-a\geq 2,c-b\geq 2$$
and  when $a=1$, $c\not=12$ or when $c=12$,$a\not=1$

If we mapping $\{a,b,c\}$ to $\{a,b-1,c-2\}=\{i,j,k\}$

the question is equivalence to
$$2\leq i < j <k \leq 9$$
or
$$1=i,2\leq j<k\leq 9$$
or
$$2\leq i<j\leq 9,k=10$$

so the number of subsets  is ${8\choose 3}+2{8 \choose 2}=112$

Similarly the general result is ${n-4\choose 3}+2{n-4\choose 2}$ where the $n$ is the length of subsets $\{1,2,\cdots,n\}$ ( here $n=12$)

Comment: Where did $n$ come from?

Comment: Thank  you very much. Very good!

Answer (score 1):

Several additional alternatives:

```
res0 = DeleteCases[{1, _, 12} | ({a_, b_, _} /; b == a + 1) | 
  ({_, a_, b_} /; b == a + 1)] @ Subsets[Range[12], {3}]; // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> ```
>  0.00042
> ```

```
res1 = Select[DeleteCases[{1, _, 12}] @ Subsets[Range[12], {3}], FreeQ[1] @* Differences];
    // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> ```
>  0.00047
> ```

```
res2 = Select[Union @ Join[Subsets[Range[2, 12], {3}], Subsets[Range[11], {3}]], 
      FreeQ[1] @* Differences]; // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> ```
> 0.00051
> ```

Comparison with methods from flinty's (`res3`), J.M.'s (`res4`) and Edmund's (`res5`) answers:

```
res3 = Select[Subsets[Range[12], {3}], test]; // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> ```
>  0.0034
> ```

```
res4 = Select[Subsets[Range[12], {3}],
    !MemberQ[Abs[ListCorrelate[{-1, 1}, #, 1]], 1 | 11] &]; // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> ```
>  0.0016
> ```

```
res5 = Select[SubsetCount[#, {j_, k_} /; Or @@ Thread[j - k == {1, 11}]] ==  0 &]@
     Subsets[Range[12], {3}]; // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> ```
>  0.260
> ```

```
res0 == res1 == res2 == res3 == res4 == res5
```

> ```
>  True
> ```

Comment: Thank you  very much!

Answer (score 1):

```
list = Subsets[Range[12], {3}];
```

Using `Delete` and `Partition`

```
Delete[
  list,
  List @* First /@
   Position[
    MapApply[Abs @* Subtract] @ Partition[#, 2, 1, 1] & /@ list,
    1 | 11]]
```

(* returns the accepted result *)

Answer (score 0):

```
list = Subsets[Range[12], {3}];
```

---

Using `Pick`:

```
Pick[#, FreeQ[Abs@*Subtract @@@ Partition[#, 2, 1, 1], 1 | 11] & /@ #] &@list
```

> returns the accepted result